# Opens Sans all styles not available via Downloadable Fonts on Android

Tags: android, android-fonts, android-downloadable-fonts

I am using [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) font in my app via [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/downloadable-fonts)

However not all styles are available. There are 36 variations available on Google Fonts whereas when added via android studio I am getting only 13. What can be the reason for this? Do I have to add them as `ttf` files to use them in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue when trying to use specific open sans fonts.
We can download and use the .ttf file from Google Fonts but the drawback would be a relatively larger app size since each font file would be around ~ 130kb.

Still trying to figure our a reason for this myself yet.